# Moving from android/Java to OC/IOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, webview, porting

I have a 30 line Java Android app which uses WebView to connect to our website.  The website was the real development and it does all the work for scaling and adjusting.  The app simply makes a WebView browser connection to it, plus it catches connectivity errors and uses Toast for some messaging.  All is about 30 lines of Java, using Eclipse.  The app is done, fully tested, signed and is being deployed to play store.

I want to have the same app supported on iphone and ipad.  My question is this:

> Is xcode and rewriting the app in Objective C the fastest and best path to port the app from Java/android to ios?  Is there a shortcut?  Is there a translation or transformation utility available?

Phonegap/Cordova doesn't seem to be applicable here (or is it?) as the app is not a js/html/Css app. I also understand that there are no plugins for ios in Eclipse. There are tutorials on how to do this in xcode (e.g., http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/) but was wondering if there is a better path.

I remember a university project a few years back that was trying to build the translator from java to objective C plus all the needed ios libraries.  Not sure if it became a product at any time.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best path is using Objective-C or Swift in XCode, since `WebViews` are available in iOS too, and your app will be of a length comparable to the Android version.